# What does the following Prolog program do?

Tags: prolog

What does this Prolog program do?  I think it compares two variables?  When I read this rule to me it says that `m` has a relationship to `m2` if `x` is related to `y`

```
m(X, Y) :-
   m2(X, Y, [ ] ).

m2([ ], X, X).
m2([X|Y], [X, X|Z], W) :-
   m2(Y, Z, W).
```

Comment: Have you tried running it? Did you encounter any errors? Have you tried displaying some of the data as it passes through this code to see how it changes?

Answer (score 0):

let's try the most general query:

```
?- m(X,Y).
X = Y, Y = [] ;
X = [_G3566],
Y = [_G3566, _G3566] ;
X = [_G3566, _G3575],
Y = [_G3566, _G3566, _G3575, _G3575] ;
X = [_G3566, _G3575, _G3584],
Y = [_G3566, _G3566, _G3575, _G3575, _G3584, _G3584] ;
...
```

so, Ys seems to be simply the Xs sequence, with each element doubled...

Comment: I don't know, I have tried to run it but keep getting errors and oddly enough when I type m(X,Y). I get X = Y, Y = [] with a waiting prompt

Comment: Ok, reply a semicolon at the 'waiting prompt'. What errors ?